# Facebook application - Add wall

Tags: facebook

How can I add a wall on my facebook-application (fbml).

Do I have to store the wallposts (user-id and comment) in my database, and display them using fb:wall, fb:wallposts, or is it a plugin like fb:comments for this? If so, how do I add a textfield/form for interacting with the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It has to be stored in a separate database. fb:wall etc. just mimics the look of a wall-

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/wall/

FBML has been deprecated. Starting June 1, 2012 FBML apps will no longer work as all FBML endpoints will be removed. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML.

Comment: This question is over 2 years old - why did you reply now?